# run loop backward in template in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```
<template>
 <li v-for="r in recent">
  {{r}}
 </li>
</template>
```

recent is an array .

I don't want to list contents of recent from 0 to n-1 .

Instead i want to list it from n-1 to 0.

I tried ->

```
 <template>
 <li v-for="r=recent.length-1 ; r>=0 ; r--">
  {{r}}
 </li>
</template>
```

But, it didn't work.

Comment: Just make a computed property that reverses the list and use the computed property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution 1: Reverse array directly in template

You can actually reverse the array directly in your template before iterating through it, using `recent.slice().reverse()`. Using `.slice()` is necessary because `this.recent` is actually not an array per se. However, I do not prefer this method because it means placing logic in your template.

```
<template>
 <li v-for="r in recent.slice().reverse()">
  {{r}}
 </li>
</template>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#list',
  data: {
    recent: [
      'Lorem',
      'ipsum',
      'dolor',
      'sit',
      'amet'
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li v-for="r in recent.slice().reverse()">
    {{ r }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

## Solution 2: Use a computed property

As what @vbranden has said, you can simply reverse an array in a method and use it in `v-for`. This is my preferred method.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#list',
  data: {
    recent: [
      'Lorem',
      'ipsum',
      'dolor',
      'sit',
      'amet'
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    recentReversed: function() {
      return this.recent.reverse();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li v-for="r in recentReversed">
    {{ r }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: 1st One easiest ! helpful !

Answer (score 2):

You should use Array.prototype.reverse()

Source : [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

**In your computed**

```
export default Vue.extend({
        name: 'mainActivity',
        data (){
            return{
                stuff: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
            }
        },
      computed:{
              reverseArray(){return this.stuff.reverse()}
       },
        created(){}
    })
```

**HTML**

```
<template>
 <li v-for="r in reverseArray">
  {{r}}
 </li>
</template>
```

Comment: Please confirm the answer if its help to you @Shivam Singh

Answer (score 0):

There is no for-loop form of `v-for`. There is a [range form](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Range-v-for), which you can use to get the effect you want (with a little simple math).

You could do the same thing with a computed, as vbranden noted in his comment.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    stuff: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
  },
  computed: {
    stuffIndexCountdown() {
      return this.stuff.map((_, i) => i).reverse();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="i in stuff.length">
    {{stuff.length - i}}
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div v-for="i in stuffIndexCountdown">
    {{i}}
  </div>
</div>
```